# wcf binding receiveTimeout

Tags: .net, wcf, web-services

I have receiveTimeout in web config of wcf webservice, set to infinite. It doesn't work though, it takes the default value of 10 minutes. and the application crashes after that.

How and where can I catch this crash? and how to put a ping or reconnect again code there.

Or if is there a way to increase receivetimeout to infinite?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're setting the value in your config file then it's like this:

```
receiveTimeout="00:30:00"
```

I don't think it's a good idea to set it to the maximum value though. Try to set it to something reasonable.

If you really want infinite, [enable reliable sessions](http://nogeekhere.blogspot.com/2009/04/why-will-wcf-client-be-disconnected.html) on your binding.

Comment: Added a link to show you how to enable reliable session on your binding - that will allow infinite.

Answer (score 4):

You cannot set the Binding.ReceiveTimeout property to infinite. The maximum value you can set it to is TimeSpan.MaxValue that is slightly more than 10,675,199 days.

Answer (score 2):

Set the timeout to max - 2147483647. Also, make sure you set the timeout for the client config as well.

See this thread for a good explanation of the different timeout values for WCF: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wcf/thread/84551e45-19a2-4d0d-bcc0-516a4041943d

Comment: receiveTimeout="2147483647" as opposed to "00:10:00" format? will that work? Thanks.